# php shorthand for or statement

Tags: php, compare, conditional-operator, shorthand

Is there a shorthand for calling an if statement like this?
This is the regular way as php docs state. Defining the variable twice, and comparing.

```
if( 0 == 0 || 0 == 1 ) dump('42');
```

It would be faster to compare the single variable twice, like this:

```
if( 0 == ( 0 || 1 )) dump('42');
```

Is this possible?